# disable multiple select in checkbox treeview in react

Tags: reactjs

This is my example with treeviewCheckbox. Now this allow multiple checked. I want to check only one at a time.

[sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/sample-treeview-1zwd3w?file=/src/components/Widget.js)

If there any suggestions please help me.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the `setChecked([...checked, ...updatedValues]);` to `setChecked([...updatedValues]);`. But still, if you select a folder it will auto-select all the items beneath it.

If you want to be able to select a single folder, without its its children, then you can remove all your `isParent` relevant code and add the `noCascade` property to the tree.

If you read the supported option in the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-checkbox-tree) you can find other customization as well.